# React state does not update on click at all

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that react states do not update immediately, but here it never changes the state what is the problem here?

It should change the background color of input.

```
class UserInput extends Component {
  state = {
    backgroundColor: "black",
  };

  ChangeColor = () => {
    this.setState = {
      backgroundColor: "red",
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button func={this.ChangeColor}></Button> {this.props.name}
        <input style={this.state} type="tag" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserInput;
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
this.setState= {
   backgroundColor :'red' 
}
```

Should be:

```
this.setState({
   backgroundColor :'red' 
})
```

You are setting a value instead of calling the function

Comment: i did it is still not working    here is my button component:  import React from 'react';


 function Button (props){
    return <button   onClick={props.func}> Click me</button>
 }

 export default Button;

Comment: I created [this](https://codepen.io/eletrolitico/pen/abpKrYr) codepen, I hope it helps

Comment: changeColor function working , but it does not change  the status simply.

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing how the `func` prop is handled in the `Button` component that you have made yourself, it is impossible to know exactly why the `ChangeColor` function is not called, but my guess would be that `Button` component either never calls this `func` prop or it is handled somehow incorrectly. Does your `Button` handle `onClick` events?

In case it turns out that the current configuration of `Button` is not suitable for handling such events, you should either modify it to handle them properly, or alternatively wrap the `Button` in a `div` and give the following prop to the `div`: `onClick={this.ChangeColor}`.

Comment: import React from 'react';


 function Button (props){
    return <button   onClick={props.func}> Click me</button>
 }

 export default Button;

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simplified example, hope that helps you.
Also if you could provide the code for the Button component, I could update the answer in case there is an issue there.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button from "./path/to/component"


export default class UserInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.click = this.click.bind(this);
    // Set initial state (ONLY ALLOWED IN CONSTRUCTOR)
    this.state = {
      backgroundColor: "black"
    };
  }
  click(e) {
    this.setState({
      backgroundColor: "red"
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.backgroundColor}</p>
        <Button func={this.click}>Some cheerful text</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: import React from 'react';


 function Button (props){
    return <button   onClick={props.func}> Click me</button>
 }

 export default Button;

Comment: Updated, this should work, let me know if you have an issue. Also, update the question to include the Button component code so everyone could see it. If it works for you Perviz, don't forget to mark the answer as correct and have a nice day.

Answer (score -1):

try setting the state in the constructor which extends the Component class Constructor.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Component} from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';
import  Button from '../Button/Button'

class UserInput extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      backgroundColor: 'black'
    }
  }

   ChangeColor = ()=>{
      this.setState({backgroundColor :'red' })
    }

    render(){
   return  <div>  <Button  onClick={this.ChangeColor}></Button> {this.props.name} 
     <input  style={this.state} type="tag"/> </div>
   }
 }
```

But the limitation is that it will change the color only once for changing color on every press you need to change state depending on some boolian value or any other working method